# Nested ordered list as multi line menu

Tags: css, list, menu

I am building a menu with css from a nested ordered list. What I am trying to achieve - without success yet - is that each nesting level is placed in a seperate row. I created a test case on codepen and I would appreciate any help solving this issue. Here's the pen: http://codepen.io/peterschmidler/pen/CkzpF

Thanks a lot in advance!

Peter

Edit: Thanks for the hint to the correct nesting of the list. But I still could't solve the main issue: How to render the list in seperate rows for each active level. I updated the code to clarify the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lzHda

I would highly appreciate any help, that solves the problem with pure CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not nest your lists properly. `<ol>` can only contain `<li>`. You should put your nested `<ol>` inside an `<li>`. Something like this:

```
<ol>
 <li>main1</li>
 <li>main2
  <ol>
   <li>sub1</li>
   <li>sub2
     <ol>
       <li>subsub1</li>
     </ol>
   </li> <!-- closing sub 2 -->
   <li>sub3</li>
  </ol>
 </li> <!-- closing main 2 -->
 <li>main3</li>
</ol>
```

This shouild put you back on track...

Answer (score 0):

Each new `<ol>` in a nested list should be put under `<li>`.

In your case, try to nest this part of your code:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="about-team"class="active">Team</a>
    </li>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href="about-team-peter">Peter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about-team-schmidler">Schmidler</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

in an `<li>`. Like this:

```
    <li>
        <a href="about-team"class="active">Team</a>

           <ol>
            <li><a href="about-team-peter">Peter</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-team-schmidler">Schmidler</a></li>
           </ol>
</li>
```